# Getting error message : You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'CS' as an aggregate function for an UPDATE query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to execute the below update query but it throws an error stating 'CS' is not part of an aggregate function. No clue as to what the error could be.

```
UPDATE [Control Shipping Summary Report] INNER JOIN tblmayscores ON [Control Shipping Summary Report].[Supplier DUNS Code] = tblmayscores.[Supplier DUNS] SET tblmayscores.CS = Count([Control Shipping Summary Report].[Supplier Location Code])
WHERE ((([Control Shipping Summary Report].MonthofProblemcaseNumber)=" & curnt_month & ") AND (([Control Shipping Summary Report].YearofProblemcaseNumber)=" & curnt_year & ")) OR ((([Control Shipping Summary Report].YearofProblemcaseNumber)=" & curnt_year - 1 & "));
```

Comment: You cannot UPDATE because you're using the aggregation function `COUNT()`.  Also, to my knowledge you cannot reference two tables after the `UPDATE` keyword even if you are `INNER JOIN`ing them.

Comment: The field CS is appended to an already existing table. The requirement is to populate it with the total count of the occurences of records having current month and current year OR records which are lesser than current year. Is there a way this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
UPDATE tblmayscores 
SET CS = DCount("Supplier Location Code", "Control Shipping Summary Report", "((MonthofProblemcaseNumber=" & curnt_month & ") AND (YearofProblemcaseNumber=" & curnt_year & ")) OR (YearofProblemcaseNumber=" & curnt_year - 1 & ")")
```

### Edit

When creating a VBA string literal enclosed in double-quotes (`"`), any double-quotes *within* that string must be doubled-up (`""`). For example, the VBA code

```
MsgBox "My favorite astronaut is Edwin ""Buzz"" Aldrin."
```

...will present a messagebox saying `My favorite astronaut is Edwin "Buzz" Aldrin.`.

So, your VBA code...

```
strsql = "UPDATE tblmayscores SET CS = DCount("[Supplier DUNS]", "Control Shipping Summary Report", "([MonthofProblemcaseNumber]='" & curnt_month & "'" And "[YearofProblemcaseNumber] = '" & curnt_year & "'") Or "[YearofProblemcaseNumber] = '" & curnt_year - 1 & "'")"
```

...is broken because the string literal includes bare `"` characters. Try something like this:

```
strsql = "UPDATE tblmayscores SET CS = DCount(""[Supplier DUNS]"", ""Control Shipping Summary Report"", ""(([MonthofProblemcaseNumber]=" & curnt_month & ") AND ([YearofProblemcaseNumber]=" & curnt_year & ")) Or ([YearofProblemcaseNumber]=" & curnt_year - 1 & ")"")"
```

### Edit

Unfortunately in your particular circumstance the `DCount()` approach won't work. Also, as you have discovered, `UPDATE` queries with JOINs on aggregate queries can be problematic. It looks like in your case you'll need to resort to a temporary table. That would involve something like

```
Dim cdb AS DAO.Database
Set cdb = CurrentDb

strsql = _
        "SELECT " & _
            "[Supplier DUNS Code], " & _
            "COUNT([Supplier Location Code]) AS CodeCount " & _
        "INTO zzz_tmp_code_counts " & _
        "FROM [Control Shipping Summary Report] " & _
        "WHERE " & _
            "(" & _
                "(MonthofProblemcaseNumber=" & curnt_month & ") " & _
                    "AND (YearofProblemcaseNumber=" & curnt_year & ")" & _
            ") " & _
            "OR (YearofProblemcaseNumber=" & curnt_year - 1 & ") " & _
        "GROUP BY [Supplier DUNS Code]"
cdb.Execute strsql, dbFailOnError

strsql = _
        "UPDATE tblmayscores INNER JOIN zzz_tmp_code_counts " & _
            "ON tblmayscores.[Supplier DUNS]=zzz_tmp_code_counts.[Supplier DUNS Code] " & _
        "SET tblmayscores.CS = zzz_tmp_code_counts.CodeCount"
cdb.Execute strsql, dbFailOnError

DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "zzz_tmp_code_counts"
```

Comment: I tried the below query as per the suggestion and im getting a syntax error.

Comment: I tried the below query as per the suggestion and im getting a syntaxerror. It highlights "SUPPLIER DUNS" and pops up an error stating "Expected enf of statement"                            strsql = "UPDATE tblmayscores SET CS = DCount("[Supplier DUNS]", "Control Shipping Summary Report", "([MonthofProblemcaseNumber]='" & curnt_month & "'" And "[YearofProblemcaseNumber] = '" & curnt_year & "'") Or "[YearofProblemcaseNumber] = '" & curnt_year - 1 & "'")"

Comment: Thanks Gord :) This seems to work. However I have one more question. I am trying to append a where clause and it throws up an unknown error.

Comment: strsql = "UPDATE tblmayscores SET CS = DCount(""[MonthofProblemcaseNumber]"", ""Control Shipping Summary Report"", ""(([MonthofProblemcaseNumber]=" & curnt_month & ") AND ([YearofProblemcaseNumber]=" & curnt_year & ")) Or ([YearofProblemcaseNumber]=" & curnt_year - 1 & ")WHERE (([Control Shipping Summary Report].[Supplier DUNS Code]=[tblmayscores].[Supplier DUNS])"")"

Comment: The requirement is to count "MonthofProblemcaseNumber"if and only if (([Control Shipping Summary Report].[Supplier DUNS Code]=[tblmayscores].[Supplier DUNS])"")